# Allow standard user to change settings in Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, permissions, device-manager

Is there a permission that I can grant to a standard user in Windows 7 Home Premium to allow them to change settings in Device Manager; specifically, the ability to change a network adapter's MAC address?

Comment: There is no simple method to change a network adapters MAC address in Windows so there really isn't a group policy that allows or prevents doing so specifically.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

The long answer is that Home Premium doesn't have local group policy editing (Professional does). You could do this if it were available, but it is not. In order to make changes to things on an administrator level, they would need to be admin in Home Premium, or have an admin's credentials.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you do this if local group policy editing was available?