# Allow standard user to change settings in Device Manager in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager

Is there a way to allow the standard user to update drivers and port settings in Windows 10?

Comment: This is an Evergreen question. The work you describe requires Admin Credentials.  This question may help you.  https://superuser.com/questions/989855/allow-standard-user-to-change-settings-in-device-manager?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow standard user to change settings in Device Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/989855/allow-standard-user-to-change-settings-in-device-manager)

Comment: I did go through the above links. Made changes in the local group policy to allows the user to Load and unload device drivers. But that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: That is because yiu need admin creedentials to make changes